# Recommendations: Any Good books to study Path-Integration from 0 again?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, soft-question, physics, book-recommendation

I was researching and talking with some friends about I want to start from zero studying path integral, this question, and they recommended I start by studying "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals". It is this the best start or you guys are recommended other introductory book before this?

Note: I have done 5 year of physics but I am old enough and I didn't touch any book of physic for several years (+15).

Comment: 2 Ways to go there from a mathematics point of view.
Defining path integration with differential forms or just with sums as they did in the 1900's. Each has its pro's and cons. Differential forms way - even though harder (at least for me) seems to be a natural way to go for a person with a physics background.

Comment: A general guide to get some good books on some topic is to search it in amazon website, [e.g. path integral](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st_relevancerank?keywords=Path+Integrals&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3APath+Integrals&qid=1460660839&sort=relevancerank) and then to **read the reviews**.